# C# Entity Framework database first symbol in column name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, mapping

I'm working on a project with a database that has been around for a long time and people aren't too keen on changing anything in it (probably so they won't have to fix their other applications).

The SQL Server database has a column named `FORM#` but when it gets imported into the C# file, it turns into

```
public string FORM_ { get; set; }
```

so I'm getting an error where it says that `FORM_` does not exist

I've tried using

```
[Column("FORM#")]
```

from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`.

Is there any way to bypass this without making changes to the database name?

Comment: And using the `[Column()]` data annotation didn't help?

Comment: No, I still get an error saying `FORM_' does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name` just like before

Comment: haha my condolences man what a name '#'

Comment: Ya, wonder why they didn't just write out number

Comment: I quess then fluent api gives same result?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works instead of Column("FORM#")

```
DisplayName("FORM#")    
public string FORM_ { get; set; }
```